# Automated category sort by sale

Tags: price, category, sorting

I would like to make automated category, where I want to have all catalog products sort by discount price percentage from the highest discount to the lowest.

Could anyone help me?

I tried many extensions and tried to change code, but nothing helped me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you update your answer according to m2.4

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer but it can get you on the right track.
There is how you can get all the products that have a discount

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addUrlRewrite();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->getSelect()->where("`price_index`.price > price_index.min_price");

$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('percentage', '(price_index.price - price_index.min_price) * 100 / price_index.price', array());
$collection->getSelect()->order('percentage DESC');
```

I'm not sure this works for other than simple products, and you might get in trouble if you have prices that are `0.00`.  So you might want to add to the code above:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple'); // only simple products
$collection->getSelect()->where('price_index.price > ?', 0); //only price bigger than 0;
```

Now you have 2 options.
Either create a page with a block that renders the collection above. This way you have access real time to the discounted products. The downside is that you don't have the features offered by a category display and you have to implement them yourself (paging, layered navigation, ....).

The second option (I would go with this one) is to have a cron that runs every night (or whenever you want but after the price index is rebuilt) that gets the product collection as described above and assigns all the products in a category and adding their position in the order determined by the percentage discount.

Your cron can look like this:

```
$collection = ...//see the code above.  
$categoryId = 100; //replace with your category id
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$products = array();
$position = 1;
foreach ($collection as $item) {
   $products[$item->getId()] = $position;
   $position++;
}
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
$category->save();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately Im too low in php so Im unable to make it to work :-(

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that I released a module recently (well v2 of an existing module) - aptly named 'Magento Dynamic Category Products', that does exactly this : It can automate category product associations, which includes any product attribute, (thus special price can be used) Additionally it can also get all the products that are discounted via a Catalog Price Rule (at the time of viewing)

and much much more :)

Feel free to experiment via the demo site http://giftpromodemo.proxiblue.com.au/ (admin is under /admin with demo / dem0dem0 for login)

The module is located on my site : http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-dynamic-category-products.html