# Sort By Biggest saving

Tags: product, sorting

I tried to make sort by option by biggest discount, something like sorting `$discount_value= $minimal_price / $regular` price;

I saw many scripts, but none of them is usefull. I think, many people would like this type od extension or script.

I tried in `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/List.php`  to add `$this->_productCollection->joinField...`  I think solution is in this file.

Thank you very much for help or php code to paste there.

Comment: can you please update your code

Comment: Maybe you can get something out of here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14417/146

Comment: I try to do it many ways, but Im not successful.